# create table from multiple tables and add new columns

Tags: sql

I have three tables shipper, supplier and quiz. Columns of these tables are:

quiz:

```
id(PK)
name
Origin
Destination
total_trucks
material_type
scheduled_date
offered_price
owner_id
subject_id
```

supplier:

```
user_id
name
company_name
email
gst
Pan
address
origin_city
service
```

shipper:

```
user_id
fname
lname
email
company_name
gst
pan
address 
city
```

I want to create a new table using all three and also add some new columns in the new table. Can I achieve this using this?:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
    (
     new columns and their type
    )
    AS
    (
     SELECT columns from three tables
     FROM shipper,supplier,quiz
    );
```

columns of new table are:

```
id
number
date
name(from shipper)
amount
origin(from quiz)
destination(from quiz)
name(from supplier)
amount
some other columns
```

Also how can i shuffle the order of columns ?

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: I used mysql and postgresql because we are working on both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need view

```
 CREATE VIEW view_name AS
  SELECT col1,col2,col3 -- select your needed column
 FROM  FROM shipper join supplier on shipper.user_id=supplier.user_id
 join quiz on shipper.user_id=quiz.owner_id --use proper join key
```

Comment: what's accounts_v_members?

Comment: @RahulSharma accounts_v_members that is just name of the view you can change it as your way

Comment: but can i add new columns to it ? (as I stated in my question)

Comment: @RahulSharma intimes of creation table from others table you can not add new column you have  to do alter for adding new column in existing table

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to create a table from select is simply :

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
   SELECT columns from joined tables;   -- FROM shipper,supplier,quiz
```

The new table inherits the column attributes from the selected ones so you don't have to include type definitions.

Be careful of column names that are the same across different tables. The have to be aliased if you wish to include them more than once.

Comment: But how to add new columns to it ?